# Editing DataGridView data and updating changes directly into MySQL database

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to save the changes that have made in the `datagridview`. I have code for adding the existing entries on the `datagridview` but I don't know how to update the changes made on datagridview
here is the code i am using to for adding the `datagridview` entries to the database

```
Public Sub ADD_DGV_CMD(SENDER As String)`
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In ALL_BILL_FRM.DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim constring As String = "server=localhost; user=root; password=Masoom1; database=airtech_db; convert zero datetime=true;"
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Insert into `all_bills` values(null,@Supplier_Name,@Bill_No,@Bill_Type,@Bill_Amount,@Bill_Date);", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier_Name", row.Cells(1).Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_No", row.Cells(2).Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_Type", row.Cells(3).Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_Amount", row.Cells(4).Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_Date", row.Cells(5).Value)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Bill date is a string? Really? o_0

Comment: There's so much wrong there. Create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid. You can build the schema yourself or have it created by a call to `FillSchema` on a data adapter. When it's time to save, call `Update` on the data adapter to save the lot in a single batch. You need to create an appropriate `InsertCommand` for the data adapter.

Comment: well i really laughed hard but actually it have to be string as date is not always mentioned as sometimes there is something else to mention instead of date so that's why but that question made me laugh for sure buddy :p

Comment: DEAR jmchilhinney I appreciate your help as u always helped me a lot well I am sorry to say I tried by my self to create datatable and adapter and tried to update it but unfortunately I couldn't do it so if u can kindly provide me the code how to do it it will be nice of you and can I have your any direct contact for any help if I needed ?

Comment: I hope that is not your real username and password. Even on local host get in the habit of never posting your credentials.

Comment: no no buddy its totally random user name and password as no harm to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class MAIN_FRM
  Dim changes_counter As Integer, SEARCH_TYPE As String
  Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user=root; password=Masoom1; database=airtech_db;")
  Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from all_bills;", con)
  Dim ds As New DataSet
  Dim cmdBuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder
  Dim LOAD_CMD_CALL As Boolean

  Private Sub UPDATE_BTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UPDATE_BTN.Click
    Try
        cmdBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        ds = ds.GetChanges()
        If ds IsNot Nothing Then
            da.Update(ds)
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
  END SUB
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding parameters in a loop. If your table contains more than one then all the parameters will be added again. They don't replace the existing ones, they supplement them, hence the "already added" error

Move your parameter adds to outside the loop. Chef get the way you work so that he parameter *values* are updated in the loop..

I would say "you should do:"

```
  .Parameters("@Supplier_Name").Value = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
```

..inside the loop, but what you should actually do is toss this lot out and take a look at using a strongly typed dataset, dapper or entity framework. If you're keen to carry on filling your button click handlers with SQL, dapper lets you do that but you might well get more out of something more high level

The short short version of using datasets is:

- add a dataset to your project
- open it, right click the surface and choose Add TableAdapter
- connect to MySQL, ensure you have installed both the driver and the visual studio tools
- enter `SELECT * FROM all_bills` as the query, finish the wizard
- save the dataset
- open the forms designer
- open the data sources window (view menu, other windows)
- drag the grid representing your table out of the data sources window and drop it on the form
- run the project

Your grid will load and be able to to read and write the dB, not a single line of code written (by you; visual studio wrote a whole lot behind the scenes - you can see it in various .Designer.vb files)!